# Error when using chrome version 117 in Python undetected_chromedriver

Tags: python, windows, selenium-webdriver, undetected-chromedriver, seleniumwire

Using undetected_chromedriver with Chrome Driver version 117 results in an error.
The execution environment is as follows.

OS: Windows 11
Python: 3.7.6
undetected_chromedriver: 3.5.3
selenium: 4.9.1
selenium-wire：5.1.0
Chrome Version: 117

The error status is shown in the image.

[The process stops at this screen.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKUvZ.png)

NET::ERR_CERT_AUTHORITY_INVALID

I cannot proceed from this error screen.

It works fine in the following environment.

OS: Windows 11
Python: 3.7.6
undetected_chromedriver: 3.4.7
selenium: 4.9.1
selenium-wire：5.1.0
Chrome Version: 114

Please tell me how to make it work properly.